# ZFC "Model" vs "Universe" vs ...?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

This question has to do with clarifying a basic matter of terminology: What's the right word to denote "a collection of sets that satisfies the axioms of ZFC"?

The word "model" is sometimes used, but the exact meaning ascribed to that word seems inconsistent. Section 3.2 of [this article](http://timothychow.net/forcing.pdf) says

> a model of ZFC has to be a *set*, and $V$, being "too large" to be a set (Cantor's paradox), is a proper class and therefore, strictly speaking, is disqualified from being a model of ZFC

On the other hand, [this article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/#GdeConUni) describes Godel's constructible hierarchy $L$ as "an *inner model* of ZFC" even though $L$ is a proper class and not a set (as far as I know, since it contains all the ordinals). So it's not entirely clear to me what the accepted convention is, whether the word "model" is intended to apply to proper classes, or only to *sets*.

I also see the word "universe" being used to describe "a collection of sets that satisfies the axioms of ZFC", so perhaps "universe" is an alternative that pertains regardless of whether the collection is a set or a proper class.

So, to summarize:

- Is there a term to denote "a collection of sets that satisfies the axioms of ZFC" regardless of whether that collection is a set or a proper class? (model? or universe? or something else?)
- Is there an agreed-upon distinction between "model" and "universe"? Does a "model" have to be a *set*?

**Addendum:**

For what it's worth, if I were to take a semi-educated guess at what the answer to this question might be, I would venture that it works something like this:

- After you've laid down your axioms (in this case ZFC), you establish the existence of a ***universe*** of sets, which is the collection of "all the sets" under consideration (a collection which of course obeys the ZFC axioms). An algebra analogy might be establishing that your "universe of numbers" is the complex numbers, a collection of mathematical objects which satisfies the field axioms.
- A ***model***, on the other hand, is a subclass of some *existing universe* that *also* obeys the axioms (if you look just at the model and ignore the rest of universe, you find that the model is a "smaller" collection of sets which also obeys the axioms). The algebra analogy would be taking a subset of the complex numbers, for example the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, and noting that $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a field (obeys the field axioms).

  - Presumably you can also define a model to be the entire universe
- A model can be a set *or* a proper class (so, I'm hypothesizing that [this article](http://timothychow.net/forcing.pdf) actually is mistaken when it says that a model has to be a *set*).
- A given model can be "reinterpreted" as the entire universe (in the case where you want to work in a "smaller" sub-universe, i.e. you want to ignore parts of your original universe by assuming they don't exist).

However, I'm by no means certain that this guess is correct. Still hoping someone can provide further clarification.

Comment: See [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe): "In set theory and related branches of mathematics, the von Neumann universe, or von Neumann hierarchy of sets, denoted by $V$, is the **class** of hereditary well-founded sets. This *collection*, which is formalized by Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory...". Thus, *class* and *model* as "technical" terms, while *universe* and *collection* ate the more intuitive level.

Comment: I don’t see anything in that Wikipedia entry that clarifies whether proper classes (non-sets) can be considered models. I’m also skeptical that Wikipedia deserves to be the “authority” to resolve apparent inconsistencies in terminology.

Comment: I've added to my original question an addendum containing a semi-educated guess of what the answer *might* be. But it's only a guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of authority you are looking for. The sentence "a model of ZFC has to be a set" is just an opinion, or maybe author's assumption that simplies some stuff. But what exactly prevents anyone from considering proper classes as models?

Comment: I’m operating on the assumption that technical terms have well defined meanings. Namely that a “model” (according to the official definition) either is or is not required to be a set. Similar to how in physics a term like “momentum” has an unambiguous, well-defined meaning (it doesn’t just mean whatever you feel it should). Hopefully the same is true of the term “model” in set theory. I’m just trying to clarify whether a model (according to the accepted definition) is required to be a set.

Answer (score 2):

To partially answer my own question:

Section 10 of Jech's "Set Theory" (1st edition) starts by defining a model $\mathfrak{M}$ of set theory as a binary relation $\textbf{E}$ over a class $\textbf{M}$, with a footnote saying "the sophisticated reader will not object to our use of a pair of classes." It concludes by stating: "If $\sigma$ is a sentence and $\mathfrak{M} \vDash \sigma$, then we say that $\mathfrak{M}$ is a *model of* $\sigma$. A *model of* ZF (ZFC) is an $\mathfrak{M}$ that satisfies every axiom of ZF (ZFC)."

So I think this more or less clarifies for me what "model" means, and in particular that (at least in set theory) a "model" (per Jech's footnote) pretty clearly does NOT have to be a set. Still not 100% sure about the term "universe" (at a minimum, I suppose a model's constituent parts $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{M}$ are presumed to be built from sets that already exist in some transitive collection of sets known as the "universe")